# Is \n not considered to be whitespace in grep?

Tags: grep, newline, whitespace

I am using grep to find out all occurences of a VB function call. I give the command this way -

```
   grep -n "FunctionX" FormX.frm

   1814:       FunctionX
   2682:    FunctionX
   3020:'    FunctionX
   3292:Private Sub FunctionX()
   3333:On Error GoTo FunctionX_Err
   3388: '  GoTo FunctionX_Exit
   3394:GoTo FunctionX_Exit
   3456:FunctionX_Err:
   3460:FunctionX_Exit:
```

But as you can see, it also gave me instances where it was not a function call. For a VB function call, the function name is not followed by anything, so I assumed that it's a function call followed by whitespace. I tried -

```
    grep -nr "FunctionX[[:space:]]" FormX.frm
```

However, this gave me no results. Is this because "\n" is not considered to be whitespace? Every call to FunctionX in the code is followed by a "\n". If so, how do I get the desired result? Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Most implementations of Regular Expressions do not consider `\n` to be whitespace.

Comment: You'll probably get an answer here but you may get one faster on http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Ok Thanks @MichaelTodd Is there a specific reason?

Comment: @CodeBlue Yes, it's because you're needing help with a UNIX/Linux command. It's extremely likely (as you saw with how quickly the answer came) that a programmer would be able to answer your question but it's even more likely that someone familiar with UNIX would be able to answer the question as well since it's not programming-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try matching on the end of line

```
 grep -nr 'FunctionX[[:space:]]*$' FormX.frm
```

Remember grep is looking at the input line-by-line, so it's not going to be seeing the carriage returns. The pattern above finds any line that ends with FunctionX with some possible (real) whitespace following it before the end-of-line.

Comment: What does the $ sign indicate?

Comment: that matches the end of the line